# How Do You Keep Mold From Growing In a Non-Running Car That Has Leaky Windows?

Tags: interior

I have a car that isn't running at the moment, but that soon will be.  Where I live, it rains 7 days per week, and I've recently cleaned mold from the interior of the vehicle.  What types of things can I do in the meantime to prevent the growth of mold while I wait for enough money to get the car back on the road and to get the window fixed?

Here are some ideas that I have:

- Car Cover:  Will this just trap in the moisture?
- Arm And Hammer Baking Soda?

Comment: So are you better to close all windows entirely and put a car cover on to keep the mold out instead of having a window a bit open for air to move around inside the car?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A new, full body car cover should shed the water so it doesn't get in.  It shouldn't bead up underneath, so there shouldn't be a moisture trapping problem.

Comment: Since the car cover would make it dark inside, would that help the mold continue to grow?  Should I put a heater in the car and try to dry it out on the inside as much as possible or is it better to cover the car?  I removed all the surface mold from the interior, but I don't think I've got it all just yet as it's too damp outside to really take everything apart.

Comment: Well, you do need to get it dried out first.  Then using the car cover will prevent the problem from coming back.

Answer (score 8):

I keep a big tub of Damp Rid or whatever I can get at West Marine in my motorhome when it's not being used to help keep the interior as dry as possible.

It seems to help, I usually empty the bucket out every few weeks and there's usually at least a pint or more of collected condensate inside.

Additional note from other another reader-
West marine has a disposable small bucket reloadable pack for about $10 but you have to keep buying the reloads. For less than $20 they had a pack that you put in the microwave to dry out and recycle, but you have to take the time to dry it out.   Seemed like a good thingfor my ongoing car application.   I was at the West store this afternoon and bought one.

Comment: They sell this at Wal-mart, Home Depot, Grocery stores etc where I live.

Comment: I'll have to check out Home Depot - thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

The #1 solution is to fix the source of the leak, otherwise you will continually get moisture inside your vehicle.

They have mold abatement solutions designed to kill mold.  take a look at this thread
http://www.autopia.org/forum/pro-details-before-after/112826-1979-mercedes-450sl-complete-interior-mold-abatement.html

Comment: I think getting a car cover and also this mold abatement solution is best until I can fix the source of the leak.  I just put new carpet in it in August and had the entire interior removed, so I'd hate to have to go through all that again :(

Comment: The thread showing the mold cleanup of the Benz is helpful.  I used a towel to get the mold dust spots off the carpet.  It looks brand new.  As for the seats, I wiped them down.  There is like a mold stain on the top of one of the door panels that I'll try to hit again later.  I don't think the car is flooded like the benz, but the carpet was just oh so slightly damp.  I also cleaned the windows so more light could get in, since mold tends to thrive in dark places.

Comment: @NoCarrier - Easier said than done.  All 3 of my cars leak to varying degrees despite seal replacements, trunk/hatch realignments, RTV, etc.  Sometimes the best you can do is put towels in to soak up the water and keep rotating them.  I hate this time of year when it rains every day.

Answer (score 2):

I have a couple of slow leaks in my soft-top convertible and, as a temporary measure until I can afford a new top, I use moisture absorbers from Dollar Tree to keep water from building up and prevent mold. It's the same stuff as Damp-Rid, but the containers are only a dollar apiece. They are throw-aways, however.

One big tip- do not let them spill. You will have a big mess.

Answer (score 0):

There is a product called Dri-It that will keep the interior of any vehicle fresh and dry.  It is the same product that is used for ocean going containers to keep them dry while on the deck of cargo ships.  It will absolutley prevent your car from growing mold, smelling musty, or other problems associated with dampness.  The website is http://www.dri-it.com

Good luck with storing your car.

**Based on the profile this user is associated with the product.**

Comment: Please see our [FAQ:May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) and edit your post to disclose your affiliation with the product website

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem out here in the pacific NW. It's the temperature change that makes the moisture 30-50deg causes condensation inside. You need to get it undercover and a fan or heat to circulate the air. That's the only way to keep it from molding.

Answer (score 0):

One very good solution is to store the vehicle inside a watertight building.  I don't know what it's like in your part of the world but in the UK, most local councils will rent you a garage for a very nominal monthly fee.  Alternatively, there are companies which specialise in the storage of vehicles.  You could place a wanted advert to attempt to find a private homeowner who was willing to rent you space in their private garage.  I've done all of these options in the past and it's ideal because, even for a leak-proof vehicle, it presents them from being exposed to the elements in any way.